# form multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am learning rails and have been struggling with this for over a day now and can not figure out how to get this to work. I want a select box in my form that can select multiple elements. I have this working with this code:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :products %><br />
<%= f.select :products, {"A"=>1, "B"=>2, "C"=>3, "D"=>4},{},:size=>5,:multiple=>true %>
</div>
```

This works fine and produces this HTML:

```
<div class="field"> 
<label for="script_products">Products</label><br /> 
<select id="script_products" multiple="multiple" name="script[products][]" size="5">         
<option value="1">A</option> 
<option value="2">B</option> 
<option value="3">C</option> 
<option value="4">D</option></select> 
</div>
```

What I can figure out is how the results get sent/stored. In my view for the "show" action, if I simply print out :products I get this:

Products: --- - '1' - '2' - '3'

If I print out :products.inspect I get this:

Products: "---\n- '1'\n- '2'\n- '3'\n"

and the class is a string. I would think it would be stored as an array, but I can not get it to work. I don't know where the dashes or the newlines come from.

Comment: You are printing the result of `params[:script][:products]` ?

Comment: I am doing this: <%= @script.products %>

Comment: This was the scaffold generated code. Originally in the new view, it was a text field, I changed it to a multiple select box. So, I am thinking I need to change my model to reflect that I want to store an array? But not sure exactly.

Comment: Okay, so I edited my controller to do convert the array into a string with: 
    @script.products = @script.products.join(', ');


before the save. This causes it to get stored as a string. This is probably okay for what I am doing. But I still think I am missing something...

Comment: Okay, so looking around I guess you must serialize more complex data structures as mentioned here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100427/storing-arrays-in-database-using-activerecord) but I think for my purpose just storing it as a string will be just fine.

Comment: That string looks like it is serialized as YAML. So, if YAML == Syck you can do YAML.load(@script.products), if YAML == Psych you'll need to do YAML.load(@script.products).to_ruby. Either way, you'll get an Array.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding the options as a has-many relationship on the model. Thus you can iterate through them, attach them and involve them in a multiple select in a (IMO) better way.

I would do something like in my model:

```
has_many :special_options
```

In my view:

```
f.select :special_options, :multiple => true
```

This would avoid the problem of having to serialize and deserialize the objects before storing them.