# Why scan method for strings prints out directly in rails and ingnore the rest of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, flags

I have a field (string) in DB that stores a list of values gotten from checkbox if they are checked:

Example:

```
checkbox1 [X] //Value 1
checkbox2 [ ] //Value 2
checkbox3 [X] //Value 3
checkbox4 [X] //Value 4
checkbox5 [ ] //Value 5
```

It stores in database the string "--- -'1' -'3' -'4'" (w/o the double quotes) I don't know why because in my form I have:

```
<%  SoProfile::LANGUAGES.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="fluid">
    <%= f.label :languages,class: "checkbox" do %>
      <%= key %> <%= f.check_box :languages, {:multiple => true}, value, nil %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

in the model (I don't want to use a DB table for this):

```
LANGUAGES = { Espanol: 1, Ingles: 2, Portugues: 3, Italiano: 4, Mandarin: 5 }
```

anyways, it stores that string "--- -'1' -'3' -'4'" for the example above, I want to show a country flag according to the language instead of putting the language name.

I've created a helper method for this:

```
def insert_languages(string)
  string.scan(/\d/).each do |i|
    case i
      when i == "1"
        content_tag(:div,"",class: 'flag flag-co')
      end
  end
end
```

that is called in my view:

```
<tr>
  <td>Idiomas <br /> 
    <%= insert_languages(@so_profile.languages) %>                                                                                   
  </td>
</tr>
```

But the helper method won't pass from .scan and will print out the hash ["1" "3" "4"] directly, it is, it never reaches the case code, like if there were a return in the string.scan(.. line of code.

How can I prevent rails from returning the hash and instead print the flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your method to following:

```
def insert_languages(string)
  result = ""
  string.scan(/\d/).each do |i|
    case i
      when "1"
        result += content_tag(:div,"",class: 'flag flag-co')
      end
  end
  result
end
```

You're getting hash since ruby returns values from .each block. Ruby returns last value from function implicitly. About your storing method - I suggest you reconsider your storage method. In mongoid, for example, you can use arrays. For active record something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100427/storing-arrays-in-database-using-activerecord) could solve your problem.

Comment: Vadim, it kinda did the trick, but now it's printing html code in the view (not interpreting it). Thanks a lot, is it much if I ask you to help me a little more with it and make it interpret the html instead de show the code into the view?

Comment: Dude! It's done. I added html_safe to the result variable at the end and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JGonzalezD right, totally forgotten about html_safe. Glad I could help, dude :)

Answer (score 0):

The `each` iterator doesn't return more than one value. If no return is explicitly declared, it will return the last object accessed in the method, which in this case is `string.scan(/\d/)`. You can change `.each` to `.map`, which will return an array of content_tags, which would would iterate over in the view:

```
<% insert_languages(@so_profile.languages).each do |lang| %>
    <%= lang %>
<% end %>
```