# Form not saving multiple ids

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have the following

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :sector

attr_accessible :overview, :title, :sector_id

end

class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :portfolios
attr_accessible :name
end
```

I have a collection_select within my form for creating a new portfolio as

```
<%= f.collection_select(:sector_id, Sector.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Please Select a Sector"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

When i submit the form it saves all other attributes but no sector_id is passed or saved.

I want to be able to save multiple ids for the sector param

what could i be missing?

Do i need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for :sectors in my portfolio model?

Comment: `{:multiple => true}` is creating a problem, i am sure you can save one `sector_id` w/o using it.

Comment: i want to save multiple ids though, any ideas?

Comment: Change your data model? You only have a single sector id.

Comment: so a has_many relationship? sorry not quite sure what you mean

Comment: but i guess `sector_id` is your foreign key, so it is not advicable to save it into the array instead use joining table `portfolio_sectors` with column `id:int, portfolio_id:int, sector_id:int`. if you still want to save an array in column ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100427/storing-arrays-in-database-using-activerecord

Comment: ok so new model which will have a relationship of has_many :portfolios...sorry just trying to visualize whats happening here

Comment: `sector has_many :portofolios, through: portofolio_sectors` and `portofolio has_many :sectors, through: portofolio_sectors`, both models `has_many :portofolio_sectors` and `portofolio_sector belongs_to :sector, :portofolio` where `portofolio_sector` is a join_table with `sector_id` and `portofolio_id`.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many - documentations explains it better.

Comment: and I guess you wanted to post your sector and portofolio model, somehow you posted code of portofolio twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended usage in your case:

**portofolio model**

```
class Portofolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sector_ids, ....
  has_many :portofolio_sectors
  has_many :sectors, through: :portofolio_sectors
end
```

**in form**

```
<%= f.collection_select :sector_ids, Sector.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Please Select a Sector"}, {multiple:true} %>
```

**portofolio_sectors model**

```
class PortofolioSector < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portofolio
  belongs_to :sector
end
```

**sector model**

```
class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :portofolio_sectors
  has_many :portofolios, through: :portofolio_sectors
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

and this might be interesting for you, must have a pro account:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

**update**

when you'll add `sectors` to `portofolio` using `multiple select`, `sector_ids` will be populated with an `array` of ids that belongs to `Sector`, and on submit rails will read this `param[:sector_ids]` that will be like: `[2,5,17,8]` and will create 4 (in this case 4) `portofolio_sectors` records with `sector_id = 2, 5, 17, 8` and for each of those `porofolio_id` will be current `portofolio.id` for ex: 2. In result you'll have:

portofolio_sectors table:

```
id   portofolio_id     sector_id
 1               2             2
 2               2             5
 3               2            17
 4               2             8
```

how to create portofolio_sectors from sector_ids you can also see this link: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging, see the tag_lis method.

In view you can access sectors with: `portofolio.sectors`, this will be an `array` of `sectors` that belongs to this `portofolio`.

Comment: thanks again.. so when i create a new portfolio, it is the Portfolio_Sector model that gets updated with the sector_id's and portfolio_id

Comment: when you create a portofolio, portofolio_sector stays intact. When you create a sector, portofolio_sector stays intact and ONLY when you add sectors to portofolio new rows in portofolio_sectors table will be created. I'll updated the answer.

Comment: ah right thanks, dont suppose you can give me some pointers on accessing these in the view could you?

Comment: Read my update, hopefully this will help. Also I strongly recommend to watch the screencasts I linked here, the revised one is very helpful.

Comment: i certainly will, you have been a great help, ill get some more reading done