# Rails - Which datatype should I use to store an array in a datebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, types

I'm receiving a response back from a GET api call which maps up 1:1 in my database. The response looks like so :

```
response =     {
      "status": "live",
      "templates": {},
      "responses": 0,
      "creator": "Marketing",
      "publish_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/publish/",
      "quota_start_date": null,
      "updated_at": "2014-01-18T16:05:20",
      "online_url": "http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/tampa-bob-gilbertson-3084-nme-survey-emai/",
      "deploy_uri": "http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/tampa-bob-gilbertson-3084-nme-survey-emai/",
      "settings_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/settings/",
      "groups": [],
      "quota_end_date": null,
      "offline_url": "http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/tampa-bob-gilbertson-3084-nme-survey-emai/offline/",
      "responses_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/responses/",
      "style_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/theme/",
      "id": 403975,
      "upgrade_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/upgrade-version/",
      "name": "Bob Gilbertson 3084453  NME Survey Emai",
      "uri": "https://fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/surveys/403975/",
      "invites_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/publish/invites/",
      "created_at": "2014-01-17T21:47:52",
      "tags": [
        "austin",
        "nme"
      ],
      "preview_url": "http://fluidsurveys.com/surveys/marketing/tampa-bob-gilbertson-3084-nme-survey-emai/?TEST_DATA=",
      "report_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/reports/",
      "version": 4.0,
      "updated_at_text": "10:05 am",
      "edit_url": "https://fluidsurveys.com/account/surveys/403975/edit/"
    }
```

As you can see, there are a few arrays I'm getting back in this response. I would like to store `response["tags"]`, for example, in my database on my `Survey` model.

However, when I try this, I get an error:

`TypeError (can't cast Array to string):`

How can I solve this issue? Should I change the datatype from `string` to something else, or is there something else I need to do to allow arrays to be stored in a DB? Also, as a bonus, is storing arrays in a DB bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here:

1. Because it's tags we're dealing with, you could store them as comma-seperated values, while still having a *String* based column:

   ```
   person.tags = response['tags'].join(',') # Stores "austin,nme"
   ```
2. If you want to be able to query individual tags (and index them), it might be a good option to store tags individually. For this, you'll want to create a model **Tag** which has a **many-to-many** relationship to your **Person** class.
3. Last, you can serialize your array to YAML and store it as a string in the database:

   ```
   # When storing
   person.tags = YAML::dump(response['tags'])

   # When fetching from the database
   tags = YAML::load(person.tags)
   ```

   You can ease your job by moving this logic to **Model accessors**. Let's say you keep your tags under a **Person** model:

   ```
   class Person
     def tags=(value)
       self.tags = YAML::dump(value)
     end

     def tags
       YAML::load(super)
     end
   end
   ```

**EDIT:** My favourite approach would be the second one, that's mainly because I like to keep my database clean and structured. It's not bad practice to store documents (arrays, json, blobs etc.) in the database, as long as you know what you're doing and why you are doing this. See the whole **NoSQL** vs **structured database** debate. The first option I suggested might cover your needs, without added complexity.

Comment: I added a short explanation in the end.

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails doesn't allow arrays to be stored in databases. You have to use the serialize function in order to do that. I've never personally done it because I haven't had to, but you can find more information about it here: [Storing arrays in database using ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100427/storing-arrays-in-database-using-activerecord)

Answer (score 1):

> Also, as a bonus, is storing arrays in a DB bad practice?

Storing arrays in a db is denormalized, which is generally poor practice as it prevents accessing it in a relational, declarative way with sql. Best practice would be to store the elements of the array in an associated table, and write active record relationships for them like `has_many` and `belongs_to`.

Comment: That makes more sense than what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the tip.